# Wireless keyboard/mouse slow detection on Late 2012 iMac when connected through USB 3.0 Switcher

Tags: kvm-switch, imac, usb-hub, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard

I have a multi-machine setup where **one wireless Logitech keyboard & mouse (MK345/MK275)** is connected to three computers through a **KCEVE/AIMOS USB 3.0 switcher (4 inputs/4 outputs)**.

https://www.logitech.com/en-sg/products/combos/mk345-keyboard-mouse-wireless.920-006491.html

[https://www.amazon.com/Selector-AIMOS-Switcher-Computers-One-Button/dp/B085915CTB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085915CTB)

It is connected to a Dell OptiPlex 3050 desktop PC, a Macbook Air (Mid 2011), and an iMac (Late 2012). The USB switch works perfectly when connecting a standard wired keyboard and mouse, with each computer detecting the switch almost instantly.

However, when connecting a wireless keyboard and mouse *(through a 2.4 GHz USB receiver dongle)*, the Dell PC and the Macbook Air detects and connects almost instantly upon the switch, but not the iMac. When switched to the iMac, it takes almost **30 to 60 seconds to detect and connect.**

I've tried connecting to different ports on both the switch and the iMac, as well as with different USB cables, but the delay persists. I'd even connected the USB Switch to a power supply through the provided 5V micro-USB power input. In addition to the delay in detecting and connecting through the USB switch, the performance is also a little choppy, almost like signal interference.

The wireless keyboard and mouse works perfectly with the iMac if connected directly.

I could really use some advice on what the issue could be. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose it could be interference. I might try putting a snap-on ferrite bead on the iMac end of the USB cable that goes from the iMac to the KVM.

Comment: Spot on, @Spiff! It was interference, indeed. I simply moved the dongle away (through a USB extension cable) from the powered switch and other power cables, and it now works flawlessly. Thank you; truly appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help! Go ahead and post your solution as an Answer post on your own Question, and then click the checkmark on your own Answer to officially accept it as correct, so that this Question post gets marked as complete.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Spiff, the issue was resolved. It was indeed an interference issue. I simply moved the dongle away *(through a USB extension cable)* from the powered switch and other power cables, and it now works flawlessly.